# Is self join possible in lookup Transformation? If yes how do we get managers for all the employees using Lookup transformation

Tags: database, informatica

Is self join possible in lookup Transformation, If yes how do we get managers for all the employees using Lookup transformation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes all kinds of joins are possible in Lookup transformation using SQL override. Write the SQL to return Employee and Manager ids. You can then put employee id in the conditions tab and use Manager ID as output or return port.

Answer (score 0):

By default Lookup transformation works as left outer join with one matching row as output if lookup is chosen as passive. Informatica 9.X onwards it can return multiple matching records so full functionality of left outer join is possible.

Additionally if you want to perform normal join you'll have to discard rows for which matching records are not found in lookup table/file.

Full outer join/Right outer join are not possible by Lookup transformation.